# Aligning display-block divs into the same row

Tags: html, css

I have a chunk of HTML to display images and other stuff together in the same box with inline-block:

```
<body>
  <div class="attachment-list">
    <div class="galleryslot">
      <a class="">
      <img src="http://www.google.ie/logos/classicplus.png" width="100">
      </a>
      </div>
      <div class="galleryslot">
         <a class="" >
         <img src="http://www.google.ie/images/nav_logo99.png" width="75">
         </a>
      </div>
</div>
```

This was my attempt, but it is clearly missaligned, the galleryslot div will contain more than the link and the image, but should work like this.

http://jsbin.com/afiqeg/3

Any idea what am I missing? I see it very out of line with firefox, the wider image is aligned with the bottom part of the taller one, I'd like them to align on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `float: left` your existing `<div>`s and give the parent `overflow: auto`: http://jsbin.com/edacib/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Worth noting that `overflow: [auto|hidden]` acts as an automatic `float` clearer.

Comment: perfect, I assumed I didn't need the float technique because of the inline-block, but this works!